# How do I run javascript code that interacts with deployed contract on ganache test network?

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc, truffle-migration

This [truffle deployment page](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts) describes how to interact with a deployed contract using javascript.

But I can't figure out how to execute this code. Should I be using the truffle console?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the truffle console, write [truffle tests](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests) or create a simple UI using [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).